# elementary OS stopped booting

Tags: boot

I have tried recovery mode and am currently trying out boot disk repair. So far I have had no luck in repairing it, so any advice would be great.

[Here is a paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13301678/) of the boot info.

Comment: What's your exact problem? It is not dual boot with windows. Why you want to do boot repair? Does GRUB failed to install while installation?

Comment: After seeing your boot info: I will suggest: 1. Backup data 2. erase disk completely - clean install eos, if possible

Comment: It was a clean install of Elementary Os but Grub seems to have gotten corrupted with a recent update I tryed repairing grub but no luck so will go with backup and clean install bite the bullet

Comment: It looks like your elementary OS partition is corrupt :(